# How to set height of container to be of relative value?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a row with 3 expanded containers; the mid-container has a fixed height.

The goal is to make the height of the containers in both ends implicitly match the height of the mid-container.

A visual structure would look as follows:

```
Scaffold:
  Row:
    Expanded:
      Container(height: ?)
    Expanded:
      Container(height: 100)
    Expanded:
      Cotnainer(height: ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IntrinsicHeight`(little expensive)

```dart
 IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(....),
 ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove height from side containers. Set:

```
Row(
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
   ...
```

This will stretch all containers to fit the tallest.